# How do I get the update procedure to work?

Tags: updates

Hitting the Ubuntu software button gets me a screen that shows eleven updates waiting to be installed. But instead of installing there is just this circle thing going in circles - all day long! That "updates:11" thing has been there for days.

I'm not afraid of the command line; I'm every bit as consistently clueless as I was years ago. I did:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which was quick, efficient and short. Plus, it didn't seem to really do much because that spinning circular thing is still going in circles, and the, "updates:11" is still there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did `apt-get upgrade` install 11 packages?

Comment: no - it didn't seem to upgrade anything. The ubuntu software butten still lists 11 upgrades; it doesn't show them so I don't know which ones they are, and the circle thing just keeps spinning slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `apt-get upgrade` with `apt-get dist-upgrade` and try again if you like.

Comment: Thank you. That substitution worked well, it ran quickly. The last line, among other things, listed 0 upgrades. However, the ubuntu software button, when you hit it, still shows 11 upgrades, the the circle thing continues to circle endlessly.

Comment: Hmmm.  If `dist-upgrade` shows *0 to be upgraded* then there are no updates indeed.  There seems to be some kind of bug with the button though that needs to be researched.  I'm afraid I don't have an answer for that at his moment.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, it does not make sense to me. I would just forget about the ubuntu software button, except that it's odd that there would be no upgrades. It's been weeks since I last tried to upgrade.

Comment: Also, the synaptic button shows no upgrades. It's just the ubuntu button that seems stuck.And it is stuck by the way.

Comment: Sorry - I'm used to emacs editing, and I don't have the hang of this editor yet so I keep bouncing myself out.

Comment: As I was saying!

Comment: Damn! Anyway, I can open the ubuntu software sceen, and there are three categories at the top. The software options seems to work okay - there are icons and lots of options to choose from and so forth - that's the left choice. The middle choice is for stuff that has been installed. It just stays blank. And the right choice is for updates. It's also blank except that it lists 11 updates and it seems to be stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem I think. Saw the related thread in the column on the right, "How do I get software updater to update?"

Followed this thread, and tried a suggestion:

In a terminal run the following three commands,

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Then reboot.

And voila! Now when the ubuntu software button is pressed and I get the software screen, all three sections seem to work. The right column, "updates" responds with something like, "Software is up to date," and the "11" is gone. The middle column, "installed", now lists the installed software.

Thank you mchid for that solution!